# In bash, is there a way I can make shorter (if or) statements?

Tags: bash

```
if [ foo = bar -o foo = car -o foo = jar -o foo = foo ]
  then
    echo yes
fi
```

To keep things more organized, I would like to try to match it to a list, such as

```
if [ foo = {bar,car,jar,foo} ] ; then
```

Obviously the curly brace expansion method didn't work or else I wouldn't be here!
But I would like to know if something like this is possible at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest using case structure. Something like:

```bash
case $foo in
    foo|car|bar|jar) echo yes ;;
    *) ;;
esac
```

If you like, you can add a command between `*)` and `;;` to be executed when `$foo` doesn't match `foo`, `car`, `bar`, or `jar`. For example, you could print a message with `echo 'wrong input'` or something like that.

Comment: I see where the confusion was since it was my way of wording it since I said "type in foo". I changed my wording a bit. I am not looking to literally type in "foo" as an input, it's more of keeping my code a bit more organized. Sorry about that, good thinking though

Comment: OK, i finally edited it to work as it shoot. For some reason I've misread your question multiple times -_-  Now it tests variable foo if it is equal to foo or car or bar or jar, and echoes yes if true, otherwise - breaks. You can replace case for wildcard with whatever you want instead of break, eg echo "wrong input" or something

Comment: Oh ok, I was thinking case was only for manual inputs, but I get it now, thank you!

Comment: @TuxForLife `select` is (usually) for manual input, so you might've been thinking of that. Btw, if you don't need to perform any operation when there's no match, you can remove the `*)` line entirely; then you could [put the whole thing on a single line](https://askubuntu.com/a/621337/22949) without really sacrificing readability.

Comment: @EliahKagan nah, in my earlier post I had `case $input in` line, so that's why OP thinks its only for input.

Comment: @Serg I just noticed that you really shouldn't use `break` here, as that's specifically for loops and, when executed, results in an error printing `bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop`. (This happens only if `$foo` doesn't match the first label.) Since that isn't your intention, I've edited this to change `break;;` to simply `;;`--but please feel free to edit further (or roll back) if that's not what you want.

Comment: @EliahKagan Oh, thanks for catching that. I think I'm mixing java and bash

Answer (score 15):

#### It looks like a bug in your code, but we can refactor it down really small...

If you had really written your expression with `[ foo = bar -o foo = car -o foo = jar -o foo = foo ]`, then it could've been simplified to:

```
echo yes
```

This test is always true because `foo = foo` is always true, which in turn is because the literal string `foo` is always the same as itself.

<sup>Though you've clarified this syntax didn't appear in code you were really using, I've kept this introductory section as it's a common mistake to do so, especially among novices. Attempting to check the value of `foo` this way doesn't work in any Bourne-style shell--to examine the value of a variable with `[`, you must perform parameter expansion with `$` (see below). This particular aspect of the problem is not shell-specific; for example, [here's a test in 7 Bourne-style shells](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11036430/).</sup>

#### Fixing the Original Code

Perhaps instead you meant to check the *value* of the `foo` variable (i.e., its *contents*, rather than its name) against those strings. In that case, your original code would become like:

```bash
if [ "$foo" = bar -o "$foo" = car -o "$foo" = jar -o "$foo" = foo ]; then
    echo yes
fi
```

This can be shortened slightly with the short-circuit `&&` operator:

```bash
[ "$foo" = bar -o "$foo" = car -o "$foo" = jar -o "$foo" = foo ] && echo yes
```

But it's still longer and more complicated and repetitive than you probably prefer. So, moving on...

#### Shorter Forms via Pattern Matching

You can use the `[[` facility's built-in regular expression matching operator:

```bash
[[ $foo =~ ^(bar|car|jar|foo)$ ]] && echo yes
```

While using `case` is probably the most common way, `[[` with `=~` is:

- the same length as a compact use of `case` (see below)
- arguably truer to the logic of your original code, in that it uses `[[`, which works much like a test expression.

So you might prefer that. *It's the method I would probably use, to do this in bash.*

If you wanted to do something like that but match using `grep` instead of `[[` with `=~`, this is similar:

```bash
grep -Eq '^(bar|car|jar|foo)$' <<< "$foo" && echo yes
```

Or this:

```bash
grep -Fqe{bar,car,jar,foo} <<< "$foo" && echo yes
```

#### A One-Liner with `case`

As [Serg says](https://askubuntu.com/a/621333/22949), can be simplified using `case` instead of `if` and `[`. That's the classic and probably the most common way.

The method in [Serg's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/621333/22949) works perfectly well, but for the particular code you're refactoring, we can write something simpler, by using only one pattern for `case`. There is no need to have a catch-all `*)` match at the end. If the string doesn't match any of the patterns, control simply falls through the case construct and no commands are executed, which is equivalent to your `if` construct with no `else`.

```bash
case $foo in bar|car|jar|foo) echo yes;; esac
```

That makes it short and simple enough to easily fit--and be readable--on a single line (which seems to be what you're looking for). This method is also portable to Bourne-style shells other than bash.

Comment: Wow impressive answer. I like the `[[ $foo =~ ^(bar|car|jar|foo)$ ]] && echo yes` but as I understand, and how you worded it, it wouldn't be portable to other shells? Do you really think it's a bug? It may just not be a feature of the if statement I'm thinking. I really like the case method that Serg brought up. Would I be considered a jerk if I changed yours to the accepted answer? I'm sure we can all agree that you put a bit more thought into it with more details and methods, but I would feel terribly bad for "unrewarding" him.  Serg, if you read this, please give me your 2¢

Comment: Not a bug, but probably a bashism. Feel free to change accepted answer to Eliah's , as I'd agree his is probably more concise

Comment: @TuxForLife The bug is in the original code that you wrote, not in the shell (I'll edit to clarify). You want to check the value of `foo`, but `foo = foo` has the literal string `foo`, not `foo`'s value, on both sides of `=`.  • You're right that `[[` is not portable to all Bourne-style shells (i.e., it shouldn't be used in a `#!/bin/sh` script), though some others, like `ksh`, do have it. • While it's fine to unaccept one answer and accept another, I don't think you need to in this case; Serg's answer's also correct and good. Also you might want to wait to see what other answers get posted.

Comment: Yes the literal string foo was intentional to make things easier, but I guess it made it more confusing. Great, I will leave it on Serg's answer. Cheers!

Comment: @TuxForLife Ah, I see. Makes sense. I've kept the introductory section since writing `[` comparisons with unintentionally unexpanded variables *is* actually a somewhat common shell scripting mistake (even though, as you've clarified, you weren't actually making that mistake in the code you were running). But I've reworded it to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Even shorter:

```bash
[[ $foo =~ ^([bcj]ar|foo)$ ]] && echo yes
```

This way `$foo` is matched against a regex either starting with `b`, `c` or `j` followed by `ar` or matching exactly `foo`.

This uses the `&&` operator as a short-circuit to run `echo yes` only if the `[[ $foo =~ ^([bcj]ar|foo)$ ]]` expression evaluates to true.

If this is too compact in order to be read with ease, you can still use the full if construct, which does exactly the same but is more readable:

```bash
if [[ $foo =~ ^([bcj]ar|foo)$ ]]
then
    echo yes
fi
```

Comment: @EliahKagan Didn't get your full comment but still understood the message, you're right indeed, thanks.

Comment: @EliahKagan You're right again, using anchors should have made it right. Also thanks for the short-circuit suggestion, it's indeed a great improvement because lazy evaluations, altough not well readable, are in my opinion always to be encouraged. Didn't realized I could have used one here.

Comment: Very impressive, I really like the [bcj] part to take advantage of the similar "ar" portion.

Comment: @TuxForLife Altoughit it might not be very useful in real world cases but still, if by any chance you can match against a regex, that's the way to go.